# Ellipse Contour Integral

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

I'm having trouble with the following complex contour integral:

$$g(w) = \int \frac{z e^{z^3}}{(z-w)^3} dz$$
where $C$ is a positively oriented ellipse 
$$\frac{x^2}{9} + \frac{y^2}{4} = 1$$
Find $g(2+3i)$ in the form $a +bi$

I know that $z(t) = 3\cos(t)+2i\sin(t)$. However, when I substitute this in (along with the $z '(t)$) the integral becomes a mess. Is there a quicker way to do this problem?

Comment: Your edit is correct. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One result of the [Cauchy integral formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy's_integral_formula) is that for each $n$, the $n$th derivative is given by

$$f^{(n)}(w) = \frac{n!}{2\pi i} \int_C \frac{f(z)}{(z - w)^{n + 1}} \, dz$$

where $C$ is a circular contour around $w$, and there are some conditions on where $f$ is holomorphic. Now, two things to consider:

- Does a careful choice of $f$ satisfy the theorem?
- Does it matter that the contour is an ellipse, and not a circle?

The answers are yes and no, respectively.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite understand how I can find f that will satisfy the theorem. I assumed to solve the problem I could just parameterize my z and simply substitute f(z(t)) z '(t) dt into the integrand.

Comment: @user299020 To find $f$, you should just match pieces: The denominator in your problem looks like the denominator in my answer with a choice of $n$, and the numerator in your problem looks like the numerator in my answer if $f$ is chosen to be ____

Comment: This would just give the second derivative of g(w) though when I'm looking for g(2+3i)? Would it not? I apologize if I'm not exactly following along.

Comment: @user299020 The point is that if you choose $f$ correctly, then $g$ is the second derivative of $f$.

Comment: Well that would make the problem far easier. Assuming I am following you correctly.  If I let f(z) = z exp(z^3) and solve for f '' (z) I get g (w)? g would be independent of w then would it not?

Comment: @user299020 Yes, that is the correct choice of $f$ (up to a multiplication by some factor involving $\pi i$). Then $f''(z) = g(z)$.

Comment: So for g(2+3i) you would substitute the 2+3i in for each z? Not any w's (as there are none)?

Comment: @user299020 The letter used as the variable doesn't matter; the point is that the second derivative of $f$ is $g$.